# Is it possible to arrange the order of movies in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

See the two images below:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way (with meta data somehow) to arrange the movies so they show in the order of their sequal (example: X-Men, X2, Last Stand), instead of arranging them alphabetically by title?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't have enough videos to test this.

Using *The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring* for example:

Open the movie's **Get Info**:
Go to the **Video** tab and set, for example:

> Show: **The Lord of the Rings**
>   Episode Number: **1**

Go to the **Sorting** tab and set:

> Name: **The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring**
>   Sort Name: **Lord of the Rings**

Comment: This would have been my answer if I got here first, my only addition would be to avoid use of "the" in sort names, as iTunes will generally remove them and you may as well keep consistent.

Comment: @stuffe, thanks for the confirmation!  I've edited in your suggestions.

Comment: You could also ignore episode/show and simply set the sort name to "Lord of the Rings 1".